# ¿Cómo puedo representar la predicción de KNN?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Estoy haciendo un curso de especialización en IA y Bigdata y uno de los ejercicios nos pide utilizar KNN para determinar la clase pasándole datos de un test.csv.
Mi problema viene a la hora de crear una gráfica para representar las soluciones.

train.csv tiene 7 columnas y 8 filas, test.csv tiene las mismas 7 columnas pero 2 filas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions

train = pd.read_csv(r"train.csv") # acorté la ruta para compartir el código
test = pd.read_csv(r"test.csv")

X = train.iloc[:, :6].values
y = train['CLASS'].values
T = test.iloc[:, :6].values

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(x_train, y_train)

#   precisión de predicción
prediction = []
for i in range(2):
    p = knn.predict(x_test[i].reshape(1, -1))
    prediction.append(p[0])

print((y_test[:30] == prediction).sum()/len(prediction))

plt.plot(3, prediction, color='gray')
plt.xlabel("vecinos")
plt.ylabel("precision")
plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(range(1, 100), prediction)
ax.set_xlabel("# of nearest neighbors (k)")
ax.set_ylabel("Precisión (%)")
```

Imagino que encontraréis fallos por todos lados, a la vez que estudiamos todo esto aprendemos Python y librerías, imagino que el fallo vendrá de varios sitios.
Se que importo cosas que no utilizo porque el código son remiendos de varias partes y quedan esos restos mientras pruebo cosas.
Revisé un montón de ejemplos antes de preguntar y ya no sé cómo continuar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que veo es que en la línea `31` tienes una llamada a `plt.plot` con 3 como primer argumento, lo cual es incorrecto. El primer argumento de plt.plot espera un `array o lista` con los valores a representar en el eje x, y el segundo argumento espera un array o lista con los valores a representar en el eje y. En tu caso, el primer argumento debería ser un array con los valores de vecinos que quieres probar y el segundo argumento un array con las precisiones correspondientes a cada uno de esos valores de vecinos.

Por ejemplo, si quieres representar la precisión para los vecinos 1, 3 y 5, el código sería algo como esto:

```
vecinos = [1, 3, 5]
precisiones = [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]  # suponiendo que estos sean los valores de precisión para cada uno de los vecinos

plt.plot(vecinos, precisiones)
plt.xlabel("vecinos")
plt.ylabel("precision")
plt.show()
```

En la línea 19 estás importando la función plot_decision_regions de mlxtend.plotting, pero no la estás utilizando en ningún lugar del código.

Por último, en la línea 22 estás utilizando la función `train_test_split` de `sklearn.model_selection` para dividir tus datos en conjuntos de entrenamiento y test, pero luego en la `línea 25` estás entrenando el modelo knn con el conjunto de datos completo (X y y), lo cual no es correcto ya que deberías estar utilizando el conjunto de entrenamiento que obtuviste en la línea 22.